# Auth0 signup in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, auth0

I am using the OIDC client for logging in with Auth0 as described here:
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/windows-uwp-csharp/01-login

I log in like this:

```
IdentityModel.OidcClient.LoginResult loginResult = await client.LoginAsync();
```

and everything works as expected, the login Auth0 window appears.

However, I also want to sign up, and I don't see how I could do it using the same client. On the Auth0 window, there is only a login option, no signup.

**Edit:** I see now that there is a "Disable sign-up" option in the Auth0 dashboard, under "Connections", but this option is **disabled**.

Comment: It's strange. I followed the document that you provide(https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/windows-uwp-csharp). There's signup option on the window. See this: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AoI4pKdRYn8Kl2dM4HRc9d3ztrUp

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I used a different client and it worked... but I still don't know what it was about the first client that made it not work :)

Comment: What did you mean about "different client"? Did you test your code on other devices?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Different Auth0 client, as in: https://auth0.com/docs/clients

Comment: You might try to report this issue on their official community forum:https://community.auth0.com/